# Problem preventing evaluation of AngularJS expression when bound with ng-model

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, xss

I have a problem with a web page that is rendered using the ASP.NET MVC (5.2.3) razor engine but which also uses AngularJS (1.7.4). The problem is that what should be rendered as plain text is being evaluated by AngularJS.

So, for example, in our model we have a property `Name` that when the value is, for example, `{{1 + 1}}` is being displayed as `2` i.e. the AngularJS expression is being evaluated:

[image]

The (redacted) cshtml page is along the following lines:

```
@model Models.SomeViewModel

<div ng-controller="RuleController" ng-form="ruleForm" novalidate>
  <!-- stuff here -->
   <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading">
       <!-- stuff here -->
      </div>
    <div class="panel-body ng-cloak">
        <!-- stuff here -->
        <div class="row form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new HtmlAttributeBuilder().WithCssClass("col-sm-1  control-label"))
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-11 pull-right">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new HtmlAttributeBuilder().WithCssClass("form-control form-group-margin").WithNgModel("viewModel.name").WithNgChange("updateName(viewModel.name)").WithRequired())
                <span id="name-error" class="text-danger error-text" ng-model="errors.viewModel.Name">{{errors.viewModel.Name}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The C# class that is referenced in the Razor view - `HtmlBuilder` - inherits from `Dictionary'

```
[Serializable]
public class HtmlAttributeBuilder : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public HtmlAttributeBuilder WithCssClass(string cssClassName)
    {
        this.Add("class", cssClassName);
        return this;
    }

    public HtmlAttributeBuilder WithNgModel(string property)
    {
        this.Add("ng-model", property);
        return this;
    }

    public HtmlAttributeBuilder WithNgChange(string val)
    {
        this.Add("ng-change", val);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Interestingly, when I look at the value of `$scope.viewModel.name` in the `RuleController` I can see that it is `{{1 + 1}}` and **not** 2.

I have tried using `ng-non-bindable` and while it prevents evaluation of the Angular expression it also prevents persisted updates to the value as it removes two-way binding.

Comment: The Angular docs specifically mention not to mix sever and client side templating, but I guess you’ve added Angular to an existing application...

Comment: @Erlend could you point me to the relevant section in the AngularJS docs? That would be really helpful. I'm not sure why the decision was made to mix client and server-side rendering as it was done many years ago.

Comment: See halfway down under Sandbox removal: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security

Comment: @Erlend Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this directive?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable

Note, this should probably go in the comments, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Thank you. I have also tried to use `ng-non-bindable`. Please see my updated question.